Showing $\limsup \frac{\mid X_n \mid}{\sqrt{n}} < K$ a.s if it is finite a.s. and $(X_n)_n$ are iidrv
As per the title, we have a sequence of i.i.d.r.v. $(X_n)_n$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and we are given that $\mathbb{P}[\limsup \frac{\mid X_n \mid}{\sqrt{n}} < \infty] = 1$.
I have to show that there exists some $K>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}[\limsup \frac{\mid X_n \mid}{\sqrt{n}} < K] = 1$ using Kolmogorov's 0-1 law.
First, I don't understand why this is not trivial. Doesn't the fact that $\limsup \frac{\mid X_n \mid}{\sqrt{n}} < \infty$ a.s. mean that it is smaller than some $K>0$ a.s.?
Second, if I was to use Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, I'm not sure of the solution. I get that $\limsup \frac{\mid X_n \mid}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a tail event so $\mathbb{P}[\limsup \frac{\mid X_n \mid}{\sqrt{n}} < K] \in \{0, 1\}$ for any $K>0$. I can imagine that there is a certain $K'$ where the probability is 1 for all $K\geq K'$ and 0 otherwise, but I feel like the 0-1 law is useless here: couldn't we just say the same thing without using the 0-1 law except that the probability wouldn't necessarily be zero for $K<K'$?.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Doesn't the fact that $\limsup \frac{\mid X_n \mid}{\sqrt{n}} < \infty$ a.s. mean that it is smaller than some $K>0$ a.s.?: Surely not. $K$ cannot depend on $\omega$.

That's right but can you not just say that since the limsup is finite for all $\omega \in \Omega$, it must be smaller than some $k(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and then you can just choose $K$ as the sup of these $k(\omega)$. Isn't that right? I'm trying to understand the flaw in this intuitive argument essentially.

Let $Y=\limsup \frac{\mid X_n \mid}{\sqrt{n}}$. Then $0 \le Y <\infty$ with probability $1$. But $P(Y<K) \to 1$ as $ K \to \infty$ [which is true for any real valued random variable $Y$].
If $P(Y<K)=0$ for all $k$ we get a contradiction by letting $K \to \infty$. Hence, $P(Y<K)=1$ for some $K$.

Thank you that makes sense
